# setting compression on hive table

Tags: hive, compression, hiveql, avro, snappy

I have a hive table based on avro schema. The table was created with the following query

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE datatbl
PARTITIONED BY (date String, int time)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.url'='path to schema file on HDFS')
  STORED as INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '<path on hdfs>'`

So far we have been inserting data into the table by setting the following properties

`hive> set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
hive> set avro.output.codec=snappy;`

However, if someone forgets to set the above two properties the compression is not achieved.
I was wondering if there is a way to enforce compression on table itself so that even if the above two properties are not set the data is always compressed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set the properties in the table. 
Try the following:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE datatbl PARTITIONED BY (date String, int time)  
 ROW FORMAT SERDE   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'  
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (   'avro.schema.url'='path to schema file on
 HDFS')   STORED as INPUTFORMAT  
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'  
 OUTPUTFORMAT  
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' LOCATION
 '<path on hdfs>'
 TBLPROPERTIES ( "orc.compress"="SNAPPY" );
```

Comment: @VikasSaxena Yes! You can do that settings the same: STORED AS ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress"="ZLIB") even though it is a ORC table. Take a look at this: https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/how-to-create-orc-tables-in-hive-an-analysis/